# Select the browser to open the link in

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

There are some ActiveX controls we use that only work in IE so for those specific applications I have to open the links in IE but for the rest of the link I open them all in Firefox, so I have set my default browser to Firefox and when I receive a link like that I copy paste its URL in IE and open it there, Now I was wondering if there is a small free application that can help with that? for example when I right click on a link - in an email- I can select to either open it in IE or FF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [IE tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/) extension for Firefox. You can click on the link, it will open in ff, but then you can just click on the ie tab button to switch to ie. If you have an often-visited URL that needs to be open in IE all the time, you can set that up in IE tab's preferences.

[edit] There is also a small application called [Browser Selector](http://projects2.mwiedemeyer.de/BrowserSelector/SitePages/Default.aspx), which you could try. I have never used it so *use at your own risk*

Comment: kind of, but not exactly. Let's say I receive a link in an email in OutLook, I want something I can right click on that link and chose which browser to open it with.

Comment: The only way to do it is to have an app that does browser selection and it is registered as the default browser. Quick google search turned up a promising result, look at the edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Avant Browser Ultimate 2012](http://www.avantbrowser.com/download.aspx) with Gecko and WebKit core.

- Change the rendering engine: *Tools > Rendering Mode*
- Change the current page rendering engine: Click the green button right to the address bar

It is very useful and more stable.